# problem on starting asking to restart tor

Tags: tor-install

Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.

i get like this error can anyone help me?

Comment: What operating system? What has changed recently?

Comment: thank you guys i found the solution i use chown -hR command in terminal